# How to put a dot before last 2 numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column with numbers.

```
[375512] [122451] [0] [0] [152315]
```

I would like to have these number with a dot before the last 2 numbers

```
[3755.12] [1224.51] [0.00] [0.00] [1523.15]
```

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 5):

If these are numbers, the use division:

```
select cast(num / 100.0 as decimal(18, 2))
```

Note that the conversion back to decimal is important, because SQL Server does not specify the precision of the result of a decision (at least not in a form that can be understood by mere mortals; the documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476(v=sql.110).aspx) for those interested).

If these are strings, use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(num, len(num) - 2, 0, '.')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Num int = 375512
DECLARE @Num2 real = @Num
SET @Num2 = @Num2 / 100
PRINT @Num2
```